# Refinish Part of Hardwood Floor?

Tags: floor, hardwood, finish

I have a large spot on my floors where an office chair has been rolling back and forth on for years. The spot is now a bit worn and the finish on the surface has faded over time. In the photo, bottom part is where the finish has faded and top right part has the original finish.

Is there an easy way to just refinish the faded part to make it look more similar to the original finish? If yes, what product would you recommend?

I'm a total newbie when it comes to flooring so looking for the easiest DIY method. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: before anything heavy, try cleaning, waxing, and buffing; i bet you can get it 80% better with that...

Comment: Is polish the same as wax? Also, will just waxing somewhat restore the color or do you recommend something additional to stain the wood as well?

Comment: it can be. it will somewhat restore the luster and bring the wood color to the surface, making it slightly darker (more contrast). i would work incrementally from least invasive to most, only doing what needs to be done. From the photo, it doesn't look like you've work through stain, so that would be a later option. nice home btw.